# Thread communication on receiving a signal

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, signals

I have spawned multiple threads from my main thread. All these threads have the same start routine. This routine contains a counter that is local to the routine. I would like to print this counter periodically. How do I achieve this ?

I know that we can use conditional variables for communication between the different threads. But I do not want to block any of my threads and make them wait for a particular signal, in short counter has to updated continuously.

To summarize this is what I want to achieve:

1. Multiple threads are running continuously updating their own counters.
2. SIGALRM is registered and it periodically tells each of these threads to print their counters

Comment: How do you plan to access a variable local to a function from inside a signal handler?

Comment: I really don't understand why a thread local variable are a concern for mutlithreading? Maybe if you would give us a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it would be easier to understand

Comment: Yes. That's what I am not getting. I am assuming signal handler has to pass some sort of message to this function.

Comment: Add an argument to the routine that tells it to just print the counter when that arg is present. From your signal handler, call the routine with this argument to print local counter. I don't think there is any concern about multi-threading or race condition here.

Comment: start routine is already running. How can I call the routine again from the signal handler. Even if I did, it will be in a different thread context.

Comment: Signal handlers can only access global/static data, so you need to assign a global variable (of type sig_atomic_t) in the handler and check it in the worker routine.

Answer (score 2):

just use a global variable as a counter for SIGALRM which is updated in the handler,and then in the routine, check if the global counter value changed, print the local counter and save the value of the global counter to a local variable